# WKWebView error: "The requested URL was not found on this server"

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, xcode7-beta3

in xcode 7 beta3

When I use object-c is all right, but when I use swift I get an error: "The requested URL was not found on this server", Why?

here is code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@interface ViewController ()

    @property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end 


swift:

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webview: WKWebView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.webview!.navigationDelegate = self
        let req = NSURLRequest( URL: NSURL( fileURLWithPath: "http://www.apple.com"))
        webview?.loadRequest(req)
        self.view.addSubview(webview!)
    }

    // MARK: WKNavigationDelegate
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        NSLog("commit")
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
        NSLog("err: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
        NSLog("err2: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        NSLog("finish")
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        NSLog("start")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
let req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!)
```

Instead of this:

```
let req = NSURLRequest( URL: NSURL( fileURLWithPath: "http://www.apple.com"))
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: `fileURLWithPath` is only used if we are reading something from the device? It has nothing to do when reading from the internet right?

Comment: @Honey What about loading file from server using file path with http ??